# How to set the image of an Image control at run time?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am struggling to get a path and add it to an Image control.

Here is my code:

```
var uriSource1 = new Uri(@"/Earnest_Individuals:,,,;component/Images/Section5bb1.png", UriKind.Relative);
image2.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource1);
```

Nothing is displayed in the image. I think something is wrong with the image path.

Answer (score 0):

In code behind you have to explicitly write this as a [Resource File Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly) (provided that `Earnest_Individuals` is the name of a referenced assembly and that `Section5bb1.png` is a resource):

```
var uriSource1 = new Uri(
    "pack://application:,,,/Earnest_Individuals;component/Images/Section5bb1.png");

image2.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Earnest_Individuals` is the name of the assembly with *Images/Section5bb1.png* you can try

```
var uriSource1 = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Earnest_Individuals;component/Images/Section5bb1.png");
```

[Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)